# How do I enable an smtp server to my own domain?

Tags: smtp

I have a VPS with cpanel and I'm attempting to setup my own SMTP server so that I can use smtp.mydomain.com.

I've looked at a server in which this is already setup, and if I go into WHM > View Relayers I can see the domain name is entered there, while when I look at my new box, it only has the username 'root'.

What do I need to look at? Where is this configuration setup?

I've heard that SMTP is on by default with cpanel, so is this just a matter of setting up an A NAME record or something like this with the DNS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up MX records in DNS, so when someone does a query on the mail server for your domain, for example:

```
dig in mx mydomain.com
```

They receive a list of MX servers.